# Ubuntu Mysql Uninstall / Reinstall

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, uninstallation, reinstall

I have a Mysql installation I'd like to remove and reinstall, running Ubuntu 14.04 on a LAMP stack.  The passwords are all messed up, phpmyadmin isn't installing correctly...  I just want a restart.

the command..

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
```

is returning the following error...

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I'm having a real hard time trying to figure out what to do with this.

this command...

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-14.14
```

tells me...

```
package 'mysql-server-14.14' is not installed and no information is available
```

While..

```
mysql --version
```

tells me...

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

Any ideas how i can wipe this clean and restart?

thank you.

Answer (score 22):

1. First, remove already installed mysql-server using-- `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`
2. Then clean all files `sudo apt-get autoremove`
3. Then install mysql-server -- `sudo apt-get install -f mysql-server`
4. Start mysql server-- `sudo systemctl start mysql`
5. Check status of mysql-server-- `systemctl status mysql`

Comment: 2nd Step really give me a lot of trouble as it also deletes the file with the MySQL name in the gems as well I have to reinstall all gem after deleting all gem

Comment: That way, in the 2nd step we would be able to remove any previous unused package related to mysql.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe strip the `--`?

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common
```

Comment: This works but I had to remove /etc/mysql and /var/lib/mysql* folders.
Ran purge and install and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo aptitude purge mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client  

sudo aptitude install mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common
```